# Using compartor/Comparable while making Queue to track minimum elements

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue, comparator

I have been trying to implement a Queue using 2 stacks and was able to implement enqueue and dequeue operation correctly. Now i tried implementing getMin in it and got into a bit of problem.

**Theory**

In theory, to implement a getMin operation, we store two values in stack- The value and minimum till now. So we will be storing these values in this way- {7, 5, 9, 2, 1}  ==> {(7,7), (5,5), (9,5), (2,2), (1,1)}. Now if we try to insert 0, first we will check if 0 is less than current min. If true then we will insert it as (0,0) else (0, last_min_value).

**My Approach**

I created a class name Element like this

```
class Element<T>{
    T element;
    T min;

    Element(T element, T min){
        this.element = element;
        this.min = min;
    }
}
```

**My Problem**

Well code doesn't compile or better to say I don't understand the concept of compareTo at all, when should i use it. I believe i can understand it in a better way, if i directly use it in my program rather than doing some dummy question

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Comparator;
class Element<T>{
    T element;
    T min;
    Element(T element, T min){
        this.element = element;
        this.min = min;
    }
}   
class MyQueue<T>{
    Stack <Element<T>>s_old;
    Stack <Element<T>>s_new;

    MyQueue(){
        s_old = new Stack<Element<T>>();
        s_new = new Stack<Element<T>>();
    }
    void enqueue(T ele){
        if(s_old.empty())
            s_old.push(new Element<T>(ele,ele));
        else{
            if(ele.compareTo(s_old.peek().min) < 0)    //problem occurs here
                s_old.push(new Element<T>(ele, ele));
            else
                s_old.push(new Element<T>(ele, s_old.peek().min));
        }
    }
    T deque(){
        if(s_new.empty()){
            while(!s_old.empty()){
                s_new.push(s_old.pop());
            }
        }
        return s_new.pop().element;
    }
}
class QueueMain{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyQueue <Integer>q = new MyQueue<Integer>();
        q.enqueue(1);
        q.enqueue(2);
        //System.out.println(q.s_old);
        System.out.println(q.deque());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message of the compiler tells you what the problem is. Read it. `ele` is of generic type T. T doesn't extend Comparable. Why would you be able to call compareTo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple:

In java we have 2 ways to compare an object.
The compared class can either implement the Comparable Interface or use a Comparator.

Here is how you can make the above code work with the Comparable interface:

**Comparable**

```
class Element<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Element<T>>
{
    T element;
    T min;

    Element(T element, T min)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.min = min;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element<T> ele)
    {
        int elementCompareResult = ele.element.compareTo(element);

        if (elementCompareResult == 0){

            // element is the same, Compare by min
            return min.compareTo(ele.min);
        }

        return elementCompareResult;
    }
}
```

Notice how I demand that T will extend Comparable himself, otherwise I would have no way of compering it.

Edit:
Also, the myQueue class looks like this now:

```
class MyQueue<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

**Comperator**

Now lets say I dont want to ask for a T that implements comparable.

I could ask for a Comparator in the constructor like so:

```
class MyQueue<T>
{
    Stack<Element<T>> s_old;
    Stack<Element<T>> s_new;
    Comparator<T> comparator;

    MyQueue(Comparator<T> comparator)
    {
        s_old = new Stack<Element<T>>();
        s_new = new Stack<Element<T>>();
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    void enqueue(T ele)
    {
        if (s_old.empty())
        {
            s_old.push(new Element<T>(ele, ele));
        }
        else
        {
            if (comparator.compare(ele, s_old.peek().min) < 0)    //problem occurs here
            {
                s_old.push(new Element<T>(ele, ele));
            }
            else
            {
                s_old.push(new Element<T>(ele, s_old.peek().min));
            }
        }
    }

    T deque()
    {
        if (s_new.empty())
        {
            while (!s_old.empty())
            {
                s_new.push(s_old.pop());
            }
        }
        return s_new.pop().element;
    }
}
```

Now I will need to create a comparator for by T.
Lets say my T is an Integer:

```
class MyAwesomeIntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer first, Integer second)
    {
        return first - second;
    }
}
```

Now using this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyQueue<Integer> q = new MyQueue<Integer>(new MyAwesomeIntegerComparator());
        q.enqueue(1);
        q.enqueue(2);
        //System.out.println(q.s_old);
        System.out.println(q.deque());
    }
```

**Summery**

To sum up:
In java you can either compare by making the desired class **compareable**
Or by making it a separated **Comperable** just for it and then use it when needed.

Why would I ever need a Comperable ?
Lets say I have a class cow.
Sometimes I want to compare it by amount of milk it gives.
Sometime by wight.

I'l make a method that accepts any Cow comperator and it wont care what comparator its using.

For example, the Arrays.sort() method does exactly that.

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

How this helps.